# "Терять время зря" плеоназм или нет?

Tags: плеоназм

*Плеоназм или нет?*

> **Терять** время **зря**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да,  это **плеоназм**.

**ТЕРЯТЬ**, -яю, -яешь; нсв. (св. потерять). кого-что. 8. **Тратить, расходовать попусту**, нецелесообразно. Т. время в пустых разговорах. **Т. часы, дни.** Т. впустую, напрасно. Т. жизнь (бесцельно, бесполезно жить). **Не теряя времени** (без проволочки, сразу, немедленно).

В словаре терять время — это уже **расходовать зря**.

С другой стороны,  это **усиление** значения, так что можно считать средством **выразительности.** Поэтому в литературе используется часто.

**Нацкорпус**

С. Н. Сергеев-Ценский. В грозу (1912)

*— **Не теряй зря** времени и не болтай, чего не понимаешь…*

Борис Васильев. Вещий Олег (1996)

***Не теряй зря** времени, твой приятель уже хрипит.*

Борис Левин. Блуждающие огни (1995)

*Но это не по протоколу. Мы только **зря теряем** драгоценное время. *

Comment: Странно, почему фраза _да, это плеоназм_ таким мелким шрифтом написана...

Answer (score 2):

> Что же зря людие творят..

Зря ~ видя, о чём-то очевидно ошибочном.

Не теряй времени зря, не теряй время, видя, что теряешь его.

Потерял время зря - был очевидцем того, что потерял время.

Comment: Знаю, что сладкое есть вредно, но все равно буду есть. Вижу, что теряю время, но все равно буду терять.